# How to fit a small image into a large div

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="width:300px; height:300px; border:1px solid #000000;">
    <img src="output-onlinepngtools.png" alt="base"/>
</div>
```

Suppose my div size is : 300 * 300
           image size is : 150 * 150

Then what I will do to fit image of size 150 * 150 into a div having the size 300 * 300 ?

Answer (score 0):

Something link this:
usign height: auto and width: 100% Makes the elemnt fit any size.

```html
<div style="width:300px; height:300px; border:1px solid #000000;">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/63/Wikipedia-logo.png" alt="base" style="height: auto; width: 100%;">
</div>
```

although it is incorrect to enlarge images, good practices say that it is preferable to have an image of the exact size that is required, since when enlarging it it is pixelated

Sorry my bad english i'm from burrito.

Answer (score 0):

You could use pure CSS without boxing your picture into a div, take a look to **object-fit** from CSS 3

```css
img#resized-image {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/800/500" id="resized-image" alt="image">
```

The only problem with this solution is the compatibility : *it doesn't work on IE !*

I prefer this solution more than the Manuel's one because if your image is not the same scale of the result you want, you can play with **contain**, **cover**, **fit** to obtain the image the way you want...
For example : if the image is 500 x 1200 but you only want 300 x 300, if you use percentage as Manuel the picture will be compressed and strange... But as he said it's better to use picture of the same size of the result desired!